# Command that passes its input through to output AND performs command?

Tags: bash, pipe, command

I'm trying to use the `quote` program to make a little shell script that'll keep updating the stock prices every second. `quote` has to access the Internet and therefore has a small delay when it runs. I have to clear the screen each time, but I want to clear after `quote` has completed and before `cat` prints its output so there isn't a significant delay between the `clear` and `cat`:

```
while true
do
   quote spy gld aapl amzn goog nflx tsla f gm msft | ??? clear | cat
   sleep 1
done
```

I want the `???` command (which runs after `quote` has printed its output of course) to run `clear` then pass the output from `quote` straight to the input for `cat`. What command does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to clear after quote has completed and before cat prints its output

So what you're looking for is not actually to run `clear` then `cat` (which would be easy: `quote … | { clear; cat; }`), because `cat` would still start printing before `quote` has completed. A pipe won't solve your problem since it runs the producer and the consumer in parallel. Instead, you need to store the output of `quote`, then display it. Store the output of a [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution) into a variable.

```
text=$(quote spy gld aapl amzn goog nflx tsla f gm msft)
clear
echo "$text"
```

This removes blank lines at the end of the output. If this is not acceptable, you can work around this feature by printing an extra non-empty line at the end, and stripping it off. The command `echo` also mangles a few short strings that start with `-`.

```
text=$(quote spy gld aapl amzn goog nflx tsla f gm msft; echo .)
clear
printf %s "${text%.}"
```

Comment: The other answers worked as well, but this relates the most to my original question. I didn't know that the pipe worked like that, so what I'm asking for isn't practical.

Answer (score 2):

Grats on getting it to work, but it looks like you're re-inventing 'watch'.

Also, querying at one second intervals might be a bit excessive?  I'd pick 20 seconds or more, especially when 'watch' can show you the differences between runs.

```
watch -n 20 -d quote spy gld aapl amzn goog nflx tsla f gm msft
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what I asked, but it gets the job done. I set a variable to the output of `quote`. I didn't think of that at first because I'm new to Bash...

```
clear
while true
do
   OUTPUT="$(quote spy gld aapl amzn goog nflx tsla f gm msft)"
   clear
   echo "${OUTPUT}"
   sleep 1
done
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `| cat` in the subshell, `VAR=$(foo)` already stores the output of `foo` into `$VAR`.

Comment: Yes, I meant to get rid of the `| cat` when I figured this out but forgot to. Thanks for the catch. I edited it.